# Ejecución múltiple capturando la pulsación de teclas en Update

Tags: c#, unity

Ando haciendo un ejercicio muy simple donde trabajo con el void update, en el que trabajo con un método que responde dependiendo de la tecla que pulse dentro de unos condicionales que se encuentran dentro del mismo void update. Todo esto me funciona perfecto cuando lo ejecuto en unity, sin embargo, no encuentro el porqué, cuando pulso por ejemplo la tecla P, que es la que tengo asignada para la variable *perro*, pues me lo transcribe tres veces: lo mismo pasa si pulso cualquier otra tecla que tenga asignada para dicho animal.

Adjunto el código.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class comportamientoAnimal : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string animalSound = "Unknown";
    public string perro = "Guau Guau";
    public string gato = "Miau Miau";
    public string conejo = "Murf Murf";
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.P))
        {
            animalSound = perro;
            AnimalSounds();
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.G))
        {
            animalSound = gato;
            AnimalSounds();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.C))
        {
            animalSound = conejo;
            AnimalSounds();
        }

        else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
        {

            AllAnimalSounds();
        }
    }

    void AnimalSounds()
    {
        Debug.Log("El sonido del animal es = " + animalSound);
    }

    void AllAnimalSounds()
    {
        Debug.Log(perro);
        Debug.Log(gato);
        Debug.Log(conejo);


    }
}
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que se transcribe tres veces?

Answer (score 0):

El código que muestras funciona correctamente y solo transcribe 1 vez el resultado cuando se pulsa la tecla determinada.

El problema que comentas suele ocurrir cuando en lugar de usar `Input.GetKeyUp` o `Input.GetKeyDown`, se utiliza `Input.GetKey` el cual hace que se ejecute la condición por cada frame que esté la tecla pulsada, haciendo que en solo milesimas de segundos pueda darse muchas veces la condición de pulsación.

Deberías revisar si realmente estás utilizando `Input.GetKeyUp` en lugar de `Input.GetKey`.